# Building CAD Models for simulations and 3D Printing

Tags: modeling, solidworks, 3d-printing

Is there a tool that allows you to make changes to models so that they can be used for both 3D printing and static simulations in SolidWorks. For example, I want to have a part printed and to deal with printer tolerance I make the part have .25mm gap from the real life part I want it to mate to. That will cause issues if later down the line I want to do simulations like apply a force or torque to a segment of it because now there is a clearance. Is there anyway around this other then just changing dimensions after I have done my simulation?

Comment: In general, you should be able to set a high-level parameter `gap` and set each of the required dimensions to `27mm - gap`, etc. Now you just need to set gap to 0 or 0.25 mm as required.

Comment: I would model at nominal, and then use a move face feature to add your 3D printer tolerance adjustment. Then use configurations to suppress this feature in the simulation config.